Can i use local variables in a generated column expression in MySQL?
I want to create a generated column in MySQL as follows:
ALTER TABLE example ADD uuid uuid AS
        (UNHEX(INSERT(
            INSERT(@hash:=MD5(username),
                   13, 2, HEX(CONV(SUBSTR(@hash, 13, 2), 16, 10) & 0x0f | 0x30)),
            17, 2, HEX(CONV(SUBSTR(@hash, 17, 2), 16, 10) & 0x3f | 0x80))))

This computation only depends on the username field and is deterministic, yet MySQL won't allow it as a generated column because it uses local variables. I don't want to compute the hash three times because its a waste of resources so are there any workarounds around this and if not could someone explain the reason for this limitation?

Why are you using MD5 at all? ...and why are you using the uuid type to represent them? A hash is not a UUID.

@Dai It's a requirement from the Java function UUID#namedUUIDFromBytes which i'm trying to emulate here and which uses this format, the various bitwise operation are also because of that

@Dai besides, my question applies to the use of variables in general.

create your own function, and  declare a variable in the function (not a UDF). Also INSERT isn't a function you can use in a generated column

Please clarify if you are asking about MySQL or MariaDB. These are different database products, and they are not necessarily compatible.

@danblack mysql does have an insert function

Thanks. I should have looked. INSERT function is indeed real.

@BillKarwin sorry you're right i'm kinda used to using them interchangeably even if i know they're not fully compatible. I see someone already edited the question.

And to further correct myself functions aren't allowed in MariaDB (MDEV-17587).
If you make the column PERSISTENT then the inefficiencies only occur on insert/update.

MariaDB allows variables in a generated column expression (this question was initially tagged both mysql and mariadb, though the text of the post mentions only mysql).
MariaDB and MySQL are different products. MariaDB forked from MySQL in 2010, so features introduced since then are sometimes implemented in different ways. You shouldn't assume MariaDB and MySQL are compatible, or even close variations of the same implementation.
MySQL does not allow variables in a generated column expression.
Nor can you use user-defined functions in a generated column expression (I don't know about MariaDB on this detail; I encourage you to check the documentation).
The reason is that the value of a variable (or definition of a function) could change from one invocation of the expression to the next. So the expression is not deterministic.
The example you show, that assigns the variable within the expression, might override any previous definition of the variable, but that doesn't matter. The general case is that expressions involving variables could be non-deterministic, and it's difficult to ensure that the expression is safe. So MySQL implements generated columns to disallow variables.
A workaround is to write a trigger to calculate your expression instead of a generated column. You can use a greater variety of code in the trigger, including using local variables.

If the RDBMS permitted declaring variables within a column-expression (such that it's scoped to the expression) then there wouldn't be any problems with correctness as it would still be a pure-functional expression and deterministic. Out of curiosity, are there any extensions to MariaDB (no matter how hack-ish) that would enable this?

@Dai I don't use MariaDB, so I'll encourage you to read the documentation and experiment with it.
